# Java - 2D String Arrays, Dynamic Table, & Null Pointer Exceptions

Tags: java, regex, string, nullpointerexception, multidimensional-array

I am working on a Chomsky Normal Form(CNF) dynamic programming assignment which consists of
two parts(I,II): (I). having the user enter a grammar and (checking, accepting) if it is in
valid CNF form or (checking, rejecting) if it is invalid CNF form, and then (II). having the 
user enter a string in order to produce a 2D array that displays the derivation of the string. 
The table must be displayed whether the string is a member of the grammar or is not a member.

The following is a desired sample output to help put this into context. Right now I am able get all the way through to asking and receiving user input for the string, but at the point where the derivation table to print out, I get 5 NPEs thrown : (

---

*****start of sample output********

---

Input your context free grammar in CNF:               <- /**start of part (I). */

S:AB,A:BB,B:BA,A:a,B:b

================ Your Grammar ================

S -> AB

A -> BB

B -> BA

A -> a

B -> b

==============================================       <- /**end of part(I). */

Please enter a string to produce a table:        <-/**start of part(II).*/

abaaaa

========== Your CNF Production Table =========

---

|  A  |  S  |  S  |  S  |  S  |  S  |

---

|     |  B  |  B  |  B  |  B  |  B  |

---

|     |     |  A  |     |     |     |

---

|     |     |     |  A  |     |     |

---

|     |     |     |     |  A  |     |

---

|     |     |     |     |     |  A  |               <-/** end of part(II).*/

---

**********end of sample output***********

---

Please forgive the overall length of the code, but I figured I had to post all three of my classes in case anyone who reads this tried and compile.

***start of GenerateRules.java***

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GenerateRules 
{   

ProduceTable dyTab;

public final String NT1 = "A";
public final String NT2 = "B";
public final String NT3 = "C";

public final String terminal1 = "a";
public final String terminal2 = "b";
public final String terminal3 = "c";

//to store each rule and not overrwrite
//and infinitely loop per the initial 
//problem on 7/31/2012's original submission 
private String startingRule;
private String secondRule;
private String thirdRule;
private String fourthRule;
private String fifthRule;
private String grammarRules;

private String[] rulesArray;
private String[] alphaArray;


private String[][] rulesTable;

private String ruleSeparator = ",";
private String ruleDenoter = ">";
private String start = "S";
private String blank = " ";
private String epsilon = "e";

public GenerateRules()
{

    readStartingCNFRule();
    readSecondCNFRule();
    readThirdCNFRule();
    readFourthCNFRule();
    readFifthCNFRule();
    forgeGrammar();
    //readGrammarInput();

}

protected void readStartingCNFRule()     
{   
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    //null condition for UI's first(starting) CNF rule
    String rules_input = null;


    //if rules are valid CNF form or not, default case 
    //set to null 
    boolean is_validRules = false;

    //condition to hold since input is volatile 
    while (!is_validRules)
    {

        try 
        {
            //user prompt for entering starting CNF rule 
            System.out.println("enter starting CNF rule in " +
                    " regex format: S>AB, or S> e,");

            rules_input = in.nextLine();

            //so compiler knows to split each rule by ',' indicator 
            String[] rules = rules_input.split(",");

            //iterate through the length of the rule 
            for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
            {

                String parts[] = rules[i].split(">");

                //provided format for delineating LHS from RHS
                String format = String.format("Rule: '%s', Yield: " +
                        "'%s'", parts[0], parts[1]);

                System.out.println(format);

        //conditions for ACCEPTING the starting rule
                if(rules_input.startsWith(start)&&rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
                         &&rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT1)||rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT2)
                         ||rules_input.substring(2).contains(blank)&&rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT1)
                         ||rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT2)||rules_input.substring(3).contains(epsilon)
                         &&rules_input.substring(4).contains(ruleSeparator))
                {
                    System.out.println("success! S>AA, S>AB, S>BA, S>BB, or S> e, are" +
                            " ALL acceptable regexes for starting rule");

                    //stores the input of starting rule for upcoming use
                    startingRule = new String(rules_input);
                    is_validRules = true;
                }

        //conditions for REJECTING the starting rule   
        else if(!rules_input.startsWith(start)&&!rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
                 &&!rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT1)||!rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT2)
                   &&!rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT1)||!rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT2)
                   ||!rules_input.substring(3).contains(blank)&&rules_input.substring(4).contains(ruleSeparator))
            {
            System.out.println("starting rule MUST match regex" +
                    "of form  S>AA, S>AB, S>BA, S>BB, or S> e, . Please re-enter.");


            is_validRules = false;

            rules_input = in.nextLine();
            }


          }//end of for-loop 


        }//end of try-loop  

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }   
    }//end of while-loop 

  }//end of readStartingCNFRule method  


 protected void readSecondCNFRule()     
{   
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String rules_input = null;


    //if rules are valid CNF form or not, default case 
    //set to null 
    boolean is_validRules = false;

    //condition to hold since input is volatile 
    while (!is_validRules)
    {

        try 
        {
            //user prompt for entering 2nd CNF rule 
            System.out.println("enter 2nd CNF rule in regex " +
                    "A>AA, or B>BB,");

            rules_input = in.nextLine();

            //so compiler knows to split each rule by ',' indicator 
            String[] rules = rules_input.split(",");

            //iterate through the length of the rule 
            for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
            {

                String parts[] = rules[i].split(">");

                //provided format for delineating LHS from RHS
                String format = String.format("Rule: '%s', Yield: " +
                        "'%s'", parts[0], parts[1]);

                System.out.println(format);

                //conditions for ACCEPTING the second rule 
                if(rules_input.startsWith(NT1)||rules_input.startsWith(NT2)&&rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
                         &&rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT1)||rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT2)
                         &&rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT1)||rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT2)
                         &&rules_input.substring(4).contains(ruleSeparator))
                {
                    System.out.println("success! A>AA, A>AB, B>BB, or B>BA are " +
                            "ALL acceptable regex for 2nd rule ");

                    //stores the input of 2nd CNF rule for upcoming use
                    secondRule = new String(rules_input);
                    is_validRules = true;
                }

        //conditions for REJECTING the 2nd CNF production 
        else if(!rules_input.startsWith(NT1)||!rules_input.startsWith(NT2)&&!rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
         &&!rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT1)||!rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT2)
         &&!rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT1)||!rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT2)
         &&!rules_input.substring(4).contains(ruleSeparator))
            {
            System.out.println("2nd CNF rule MUST match regex" +
                    "of either A>AA, A>AB, B>BB, or B>BA. Please re-enter.");


            is_validRules = false;

            rules_input = in.nextLine();
            }


          }//end of for-loop 


        }//end of try-loop  

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }   
    }//end of while-loop 

  }//end of readSecondCNFRule method 

 protected void readThirdCNFRule()     
    {   
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String rules_input = null;


        //if rules are valid CNF form or not, default case 
        //set to null 
        boolean is_validRules = false;

        //condition to hold since input is volatile 
        while (!is_validRules)
        {

            try 
            {
                //user prompt for entering 3rd CNF rule 
                System.out.println("enter 3rd CNF rule in regex " +
                        "A>AA, or B>BB,");

                rules_input = in.nextLine();

                //so compiler knows to split each rule by ',' indicator 
                String[] rules = rules_input.split(",");

                //iterate through the length of the rule 
                for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
                {

                    String parts[] = rules[i].split(">");

                    //provided format for delineating LHS from RHS
                    String format = String.format("Rule: '%s', Yield: " +
                            "'%s'", parts[0], parts[1]);

                    System.out.println(format);

                    //conditions for ACCEPTING the 3rd rule 
                    if(rules_input.startsWith(NT1)||rules_input.startsWith(NT2)&&rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
                             &&rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT1)||rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT2)
                             &&rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT1)||rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT2)
                             &&rules_input.substring(4).contains(ruleSeparator))
                    {
                        System.out.println("success! A>AA, A>AB, B>BB, or B>BA are " +
                                "ALL acceptable regexes for 3rd rule ");

                        //stores the input of 3rd CNF rule for upcoming use
                        thirdRule = new String(rules_input);
                        is_validRules = true;
                    }

            //conditions for REJECTING the 3rd CNF production 
            else if(!rules_input.startsWith(NT1)||!rules_input.startsWith(NT2)&&!rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
             &&!rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT1)||!rules_input.substring(2).contains(NT2)
             &&!rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT1)||!rules_input.substring(3).contains(NT2)
             &&!rules_input.substring(4).contains(ruleSeparator))
                {
                System.out.println("3rd CNF rule MUST match regex" +
                        "of either A>AA, A>AB, B>BB, or B>BA. Please re-enter.");

                is_validRules = false;

                rules_input = in.nextLine();
                }

              }//end of for-loop 

            }//end of try-loop  

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }   
        }//end of while-loop 

      }//end of readThirdCNFRule method 

 protected void readFourthCNFRule()     
    {   
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String rules_input = null;

        //if rules are valid CNF form or not, default case 
        //set to null 
        boolean is_validRules = false;

        //condition to hold since input is volatile 
        while (!is_validRules)
        {
            try 
            {
                //user prompt for entering 4th CNF rule 
                System.out.println("enter 4th CNF rule in regex " +
                        "A>a, or B>b,");

                rules_input = in.nextLine();

                //so compiler knows to split each rule by ',' indicator 
                String[] rules = rules_input.split(",");

                //iterate through the length of the rule 
                for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
                {

                    String parts[] = rules[i].split(">");

                    //provided format for delineating LHS from RHS
                    String format = String.format("Rule: '%s', Yield: " +
                            "'%s'", parts[0], parts[1]);

                    System.out.println(format);

                    //conditions for ACCEPTING the 4th rule 
                    if(rules_input.startsWith(NT1)||rules_input.startsWith(NT2)&&rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
                             &&rules_input.substring(2).contains(terminal1)||rules_input.substring(2).contains(terminal2)
                             &&rules_input.substring(3).contains(ruleSeparator))
                    {
                        System.out.println("success! A>a, or B>b are " +
                                "ALL acceptable regexes for 4th rule ");

                        //stores the input of 4th CNF rule for upcoming use
                        fourthRule = new String(rules_input);
                        is_validRules = true;
                    }

            //conditions for REJECTING the 4th CNF rule 
            else if(!rules_input.startsWith(NT1)||!rules_input.startsWith(NT2)&&!rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
                     &&!rules_input.substring(2).contains(terminal1)||!rules_input.substring(2).contains(terminal2)
                     &&!rules_input.substring(3).contains(ruleSeparator))
                {
                System.out.println("4th CNF rule MUST match regex" +
                        "of either A>a, or B>b,  . Please re-enter.");


                is_validRules = false;

                rules_input = in.nextLine();
                }


              }//end of for-loop 


            }//end of try-loop  

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }   
        }//end of while-loop 

      }//end of readFourthCNFRule method 

 protected void readFifthCNFRule()     
 {  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String rules_input = null;


        //if rules are valid CNF form or not, default case 
        //set to null 
        boolean is_validRules = false;

        //condition to hold since input is volatile 
        while (!is_validRules)
        {

            try 
            {
                //user prompt for entering 5th CNF rule 
                System.out.println("enter 5th CNF rule in regex " +
                        "A>a, or B>b,");

                rules_input = in.nextLine();

                //so compiler knows to split each rule by ',' indicator 
                String[] rules = rules_input.split(",");

                //iterate through the length of the rule 
                for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
                {

                    String parts[] = rules[i].split(">");

                    //provided format for delineating LHS from RHS
                    String format = String.format("Rule: '%s', Yield: " +
                            "'%s'", parts[0], parts[1]);

                    System.out.println(format);

                    //conditions for ACCEPTING the 5th rule 
                    if(rules_input.startsWith(NT1)||rules_input.startsWith(NT2)&&rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
                             &&rules_input.substring(2).contains(terminal1)||rules_input.substring(2).contains(terminal2)
                             &&rules_input.substring(3).contains(ruleSeparator))
                    {
                        System.out.println("success! A>a, or B>b are " +
                                "ALL acceptable regexes for 5th rule ");

                        //stores the input of 5th CNF rule for upcoming use
                        fifthRule = new String(rules_input);
                        is_validRules = true;
                    }

            //conditions for REJECTING the 5th CNF rule 
            else if(!rules_input.startsWith(NT1)||!rules_input.startsWith(NT2)&&!rules_input.substring(1).equals(ruleDenoter)
                     &&!rules_input.substring(2).contains(terminal1)||!rules_input.substring(2).contains(terminal2)
                     &&!rules_input.substring(3).contains(ruleSeparator))
                {
                System.out.println("5th CNF rule MUST match regex" +
                        "of either A>a, or B>b,  . Please re-enter.");


                is_validRules = false;

                rules_input = in.nextLine();
                }


              }//end of for-loop 


            }//end of try-loop  

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }   
        }//end of while-loop 

      }//end of readFifthCNFRule method 
 /**
  * my protected void forgeGrammar() method
  * description: aggregates all CNF rules into one
  * string and removes the commas before converting
  * the rules(grammar) into a 2D array. then, takes
  * ui from user (alphaString) so can pass by reference
  * to ProduceTable.java 
  * @param - no-arg
  * @return - n/a
  */
protected void forgeGrammar()
{

    //this verifies that all 5 rules displayed in the console are valid
    grammarRules = new String(startingRule + secondRule + thirdRule + fourthRule + fifthRule);

    rulesArray = new String[grammarRules.length()];

    //remove the commas from the grammar  
    rulesArray = grammarRules.split("[,]");

    //convert the grammar to a 2D String array
    rulesTable = new String[rulesArray.length][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < rulesTable.length; i++)
    {
        String[] rulesMatrix = rulesArray[i].split(blank);

        for(int j = 0; j < rulesMatrix.length; j++)
        {
            rulesTable[i][j] = rulesMatrix[j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rulesTable.length; i++)
    {
        /**intermittent print out, compilation checkpoint*/
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rulesTable[i]));
    }

    //new Scanner instance to receive the alpha string 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String alpha_input = null;

    //the printout prompt for user to enter the grammar 
    //string  
    System.out.println("enter a string please using only " +
            "terminals a or b with no whitespaces");

    alpha_input = in.nextLine();

    //initialize alphaArray 
    alphaArray = new String[alpha_input.length()];

    //check for valid string entry 
    for(int i = 0; i < alpha_input.length(); i++)
    {
        String temp = Character.toString(alpha_input.charAt(i));
        if(alphaStringTest(temp))
        {
            alphaArray[i] = temp;
        }
        else      
        {
            System.out.println("alpha string must contain only" +
                    "a or b . please re-enter.");
            alpha_input = in.nextLine();
        }
    }

    dyTab = new ProduceTable(rulesTable, alphaArray);
}//end of forgeGrammar method 



/**
 * my public Boolean alphaStringTest method
 * @param String ui - the input string to test
 * (pass by 'reference')
 * @return - (Boolean) whether user input 
 */

public Boolean alphaStringTest(String ui)
{
    String a = "a";
    String b = "b";

    if(ui.equals(a)||ui.equals(b))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}//end of alphaStringTest method
//end of GenerateRules.java
}
```

***end of GenerateRules.java***

Next, is the ProduceTable class:

***start of ProduceTable.java***

```
public class ProduceTable 
{
private String[][] dynamicTable;
private String[][] rulesTable;
private String[] alphaArray;

/**
 * my ProduceTable class constructor
 * @param rt - pass by reference from GR.java (line 573)
 * @param alph - pass by reference from GR.java (line 573)
 */
public ProduceTable(String[][] rt, String[] alph) 
{ 
    //'re'-initializing the rulesTable and the 
    //ui alpha string 
    rulesTable = new String[rt.length][rt[0].length];
            for(int i = 0; i <rt.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j <rt[0].length; j++)
                {
                    rulesTable[i][j] = rt[i][j];
                }            
            }
            try
            {
                alphaArray = new String[alph.length]; 

            System.arraycopy(alph, 0, alphaArray, 0, alph.length);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("null input string" + ex);
            }

            run716();
}//end of class constructor 

/**
 * my public void run716 method
 * description: algo which implements the proof idea of a context-free grammar
 * in CNF (G) generating the context-free lang. L . in other words,
 * this algo generates a table for L(G) and lets the user know if their alphaString
 * is/is not a member of L(G).
 * @param - no -arg
 * @return - n/a
 * 
 */
public void run716() 
{



        //the dynamic table created as a new string[][] with the 
        //length of the String[] alphaArray, as previously received,
        //as its defaulted input 
        dynamicTable = new String[alphaArray.length][alphaArray.length];

        //call to external method to prevent the word 'null' from printing
        //out in dynamicTable and instead insert blank spaces.
        trim();

                //2,3.iterate through each variable A (we are examining
                //each substring of length 1

                for(int i =0; i < alphaArray.length; i++)
                {       

                        //4.test if A-->b is 
                        //a valid rule at b = wi (where wi.length = 1)
                       for(int a=0;a<rulesTable[0].length;a++)
                       {

                    // boolean condition for wi = 1 
                           if(alphaArray[i].equals(rulesTable[1][a]))
                           {

                               //5. if A-->b is a rule, place A in the table
                               dynamicTable[i][i] = rulesTable [0][a];
                           }

                       }
                }

                //6. for l = 2 to n where l = length of substring 
                //this is for iterating upon substrings of min. len. 2
                for(int l=1; l<alphaArray.length;l++)
                {   

                    //7. i = starting position of substring, i.e. for i = 1
                    //to n - l + 1
                    for(int i=0; i<rulesTable.length-l; i++)
                    {

                        //8. let j = i + l - 1, (technically, the -1 is covered
                        //in (7, above), where i is iterated until < rulesTable.length - 1,
                        //i.e., wherein j = end position of substring. Hence, j = i + l. 
                        int j = i+l;   

                        //9. for k = i to j - 1, k < j , where k is the 
                        //'split' position 'declaration' BEFORE the 
                        //A-->BC rule form cases are examined 
                        for(int k=i; k<j ;k++)
                        {   
                            //where substring_marker is used as the 
                            //split marker for each rule A-->BC 
                            for(int substring_marker=0; substring_marker<rulesTable[0].length; substring_marker++)
                            {   
                                //conditions for where the substring length 
                                //is greater than or equal to 2, pivoting from
                                //the second row onward 
                                if(rulesTable[1][substring_marker].length() >= 2)
                                {      

                                //allows a printout for a blank above the diagonal;
                                //i.e., a blank occurs in the table iff the 2 terminals
                                //below it cannot be produced in any one step by any
                                //available rule in the grammar 
                                if(!dynamicTable[i][k].equals(" ") && !dynamicTable
                                        [k+1][j].equals(" "))
                                {   

                                    //10 for each rule A--> BC, if table(i,k) 
                                    //contains B and table(k+1,j) contains
                                    //C, put A in table(i,j),
                                    if(dynamicTable[i][k].equals(rulesTable[1][substring_marker].substring(0,1))
                                            &&dynamicTable[k+1][j].equals(rulesTable[1][substring_marker].substring(1,2)))
                                    {
                                        //11.if table(i,k) contains B and table(k+1,j) 
                                        //contains C, put A in table(i,j)
                                        dynamicTable[i][j]= rulesTable[0][substring_marker]; 
                                    }
                                }
                                }
                            }                    
                        }
                    }
                }


                print7162D();
                grammarMember();

    }//end of run716 method 

/**
 * my public static void printAlgo2d() 
 * description: provides some printout formatting
 * for the table to make it more grid-like and 
 * readable
 * @param - no-arg
 * @return - none 
 */
public void print7162D()
{
    //row iterator for alphaString
    for(int k=0;k<dynamicTable.length;k++)
    {
        //col iterator for alphaString 
        for(int j=0; j<dynamicTable[0].length; j++)
        {
            //prints out vertical line to create a 'grid'-like
            //structure for the table, help with readability,
            //and delineate between variables 
            System.out.print(dynamicTable[k][j] + "|");
        }

            //prints out a space between each row 
            System.out.println();

            //prints horizontal line-dash to help with
            //readability and aesthetic structure between rows
            System.out.println("-----");
     }

}//end of print7162D        

/**
 * my public void trim() method 
 * description: compensates for variation in ui
 * alphaString input length, supplanting the word
 * 'null' with blank whitespace
 * @param - no-arg
 * @return - n/a
 */
public void trim()
{
    for(int k=0;k<dynamicTable.length;k++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<dynamicTable[0].length; j++)
        {
            dynamicTable[k][j]= " ";
        }
    }
}

/**
 * my public void grammarMember method
 * description: provides the printout for the table
 * @param - no-arg
 * @return - n/a
 */
public void grammarMember()
{
    if (dynamicTable[0][alphaArray.length - 1].indexOf("S") == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("alphaString is not a member of L(G)");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("alphaString is a member of L(G)");
    }
}//end of grammarMember method 
//end of ProduceTable.java 
}
```

***end of ProduceTable.java***

and finally, a quick little TestHarness class to throw it all together

***TestHarness.java***

```
public class TestHarness 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String[][] p = null;
    GenerateRules grrr = new GenerateRules ();
    grrr.readStartingCNFRule();
    grrr.readSecondCNFRule();
    grrr.readThirdCNFRule();
    grrr.readFourthCNFRule();
    grrr.readFifthCNFRule();
    grrr.forgeGrammar();
    ProduceTable pt = new ProduceTable(p, args);
    pt.run716();
    pt.print7162D();
    pt.grammarMember();
    pt.trim();

}
}
```

If you happen to be so kind as to compile this, here is a quick demo of how to enter the grammar in my program:

```
enter starting CNF rule in  regex format: S>AB, or S> e,
S>AB,
Rule: 'S', Yield: 'AB'
yes! S>AA, S>AB, S>BA, S>BB, or S> e, are valid 1st regexes  



enter 2nd CNF rule in regex A>AA, or B>BB,
A>AA,
Rule: 'A', Yield: 'AA'
success! A>AA, A>AB, B>BB, or B>BA are ALL valid 2nd regexes

enter 3rd CNF rule in regex A>AA, or B>BB,
B>BB,
Rule: 'B', Yield: 'BB'
yes! A>AA, A>AB, B>BB, or B>BA are ALL valid 3rd regexes

enter 4th CNF rule in regex A>a, or B>b,
A>a,
Rule: 'A', Yield: 'a'
success! A>a, or B>b are ALL valid regexes for 4th rule 

enter 5th CNF rule in regex A>a, or B>b,
B>b,
Rule: 'B', Yield: 'b'
success! A>a, or B>b are ALL acceptable regexes for 5th rule 
==========Your Grammar:======
Rule: 'S', Yield: 'AB'
Rule: 'A', Yield: 'AA'
Rule: 'B', Yield: 'BB'
Rule: 'A', Yield: 'a'
Rule: 'B', Yield: 'b'
```

if anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated. thank you. the 5 NPEs are generated immedately after hitting return to input the grammar string

Comment: I did compile and test; when I'm asked for the third/fifth rule, B>BB/B>b aren't accepted. Which NullPointerExceptions do you mean? I only get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after entering the string for which a derivation is supposed to be generated.

Comment: My bad re: the clarification. The revised 'format' (i.e., a working grammar; as I've tried this one) would be: 1. "S>AB," 2. "A>AB," 3."B>BB,"  4. "A>a," , and 5. "B>b," .  It should work with that input. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the expected output when the rules are converted to a 2D array? With your code only the first element in each inner array has values. All else are nulls which you are trying to use later. So give us an expected output of the 2D array.

Comment: @AlexVelarde: I'm still getting the message "3rd CNF rule MUST match regexof either A>AA, A>AB, B>BB, or B>BA. Please re-enter." if I enter B>BB for the third rule, and the same problem goes for the fifth rule with B>b. EDIT: the problem was that it expected a "," after B>BB resp. B>b . I'll take a look at the NPE now.

Comment: @Satyajit I'm glad you mentioned that. Ideally, the expected output should be'open' to the length of the user's string input call it 'l. If l = 3 then it means to produce an [n]x[n], i.e. [3][3], where, if the string was "aba", the coordinates of each part of that string would be printed as a[0,0], b[1,1], and a[2,2], respectively as a 'diagonal'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises in this line in ProduceTable.java:

```
if (rulesTable[1][substring_marker].length() >= 2)
```

I'm not sure what those loops do exactly, didn't have time to read all of that. What I assume though is that it should be something like

```
if (rulesTable[k][substring_marker].length() >= 2)
```

I would start by checking whether the counters are all set up as intended and whether the array indices are correct.

Also, it's not 5 NullPointerExceptions you see, it's the stack trace of 1 NPE.

Comment: @ G.Bach I see what you mean; I will re-check the counter values according to the algo. Also, tyvm re: the reality check on the NPEs.